# Change the argument name of a function, then draw the curve

Tags: r, expression, eval

For some reason I do not want to use `x` as the name of the variable.

```
mse <- function(h) {
    h + (1/h)
}
```

The `curve` function in R seems to require `x` to be the name of the argument. So I do

```
cl <- quote(mse(h))
cl[[2]] <- parse(text = 'x')[[1]]
```

Now this works

```
curve(expr = eval(cl, list(x)))
```

But the following does not work, could anyone help explain why? Thank you.

```
curve(expr = function(x){eval(cl)})
```

Comment: [`?curve`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/graphics/html/curve.html) lists `xname: character string giving the name to be used for the x axis`.

Comment: Is it the **label on the X axis** that is your problem? Because `curve(mse)` runs fine.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have no idea, `curve(expr = mse, xname ='h')` does not work also. I should specify `mse(h)`.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @李哲源 and @r2evans, I will simply do:

```
curve(expr = mse(h), xname = 'h')
```

Comment: Thank you very much. But firstly, not everyone is as intelligent as you. I have Dyslexia. Secondly, it is not easy to find a job nowadays. regards.

Comment: If you have dyslexia, then it would seem even more important to read the Details sections of help pages. The paragraph starting with "The way `curve` handles `expr` has caused confusion." describes the reason for the `xname` parameter being the answer when providing a function to curve.

Comment: ok, thank you very much Sir. Next time, I will try to be more careful. I forgot whether I checked `curve`'s help page or not, but I indeed looked it up in the internet. It must be that the key words I used were not accurate enough. So my search did not return the `curve`'s official help page. In any case, thank you. Best regards, and have a good day.